# Tools replace in AndroidManifest

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

Can someone explain what is:

```
tools:replace = "icon, label"
```

and what is difference between this:

```
tools:replace="android:icon,android:allowBackup,android:label"
```

Answer (score 2):

They're essentially the same, just different in how they are namespaced. Basically, if an app has `tools:replace` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, that indicates that the app is dependent on a `.aar` that already has these properties set in its `AndroidManifest.xml`. Using `tools:replace` overrides the values already set in the `.aar` dependency. This is necessary because if there are property conflicts between the app and its dependent .aars, the app will not compile.

For example, if the .aar dependency has `android:allowBackup` set to true, but the consuming application sets `android:allowBackup` to false, you either have to use `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` or the app will not compile.